# Как вставить пробел в строке между цифрами и буквами?

Tags: java

Есть строка типа "дом15/2".
Каким образом можно найти границу между буквами и цифрами и поставить туда пробел.
Проблема именно в определении, что в текущем символе не строка.

Answer (score 4):

```
String addr = "дом15/2";
System.out.println(String.join(" ", addr.split("(?<=[а-я]+)(?=\\d+)")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так:

```
String text = "дом15/2 2/4a";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text);
for (int i = 1; i < builder.length(); i++)
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(builder.charAt(i - 1))
                && Character.isDigit(builder.charAt(i)))
          builder.insert(i, ' ');

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```